# Google Fit subscription

Tags: android, google-fit

1.
It is necessary to subscribe to the particular data type and addDataType at the fitnessoption.builder when you want to retrieve the particular datatype right?

**For example**

```
FitnessOptions fitnessOptions =
    FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
```

**and**

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
```

However, I am not able to add 'more than one' subscription in the getRecordingClient. I will need to retrieve many different data types. Is there any way I can subscribe the datatype in one block of code? Or what should I do?

2. The second problem is when I make a read request builder, I aggregated two different data types into a bucket like this

   `Task<DataReadResponse> response = Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
           .readData(new DataReadRequest.Builder()
           .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
           .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)`

It should be having 2 datasets in this bucket right? Is there any way I can iterate both datasets at the same time so that I can print out together in a single for ( : )loop?

**Like this**

```
for (DataPoint dataPoint : bucket.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED).getDataPoints()) {
                  //stepObject.setSteps(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asString());
                  //Log.i(TAG, "Steps" + dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt());
                  //Log.i(TAG, "Distance" + dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat());
                  Log.i(TAG, "Calories: " + dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).asFloat());
              }
```